# Reading objects from a .dat file using Java

Tags: java, serializable

I have 3 objects of type Fraction in a .dat file and I'm trying to read the contents of the .dat file using Java.

With the following block of code below, I keep getting a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Fraction cannot be cast to class [LFraction; (Fraction and [LFraction; are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Mod8Problem1.main(Mod8Problem1.java:26)
```

I've tried a few things but I keep getting the same exception.  What would be the best way to fix this?

```
try(
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("SerialF.dat"))
) {
    Fraction[] updatedFractions = (Fraction[]) (input.readObject());

    for (int i = 0; i < updatedFractions.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(updatedFractions[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to deserialize a `Fraction`, but the variable you use to reference it is a `Fraction[]`. You'll need to loop an read each `Fraction` object individually; `readObject()` is returning a `Fraction`, not a `Fraction[]`.

Comment: @Dioxin can you help me to understand why this block of code works:

try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("array.dat"));
)

int[] numbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());

Comment: Because `array.dat` was serialized as an array. Arrays are objects, and can be serialized. However, `SerialF` is not a serialized array. Writing multiple objects to the same file is not the same as serializing an array. Sounds like `SerialF` serialized multiple objects to the same file, while `array` simply serialized an array (one object).

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I have 3 objects of type Fraction in a .dat_ No, you don't. You can only serialize a single object in java, however that single object may be a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or an array, in other words a single object that **contains** several, other objects. How was file _SerialF.dat_ created?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Fraction[] updatedFractions = (Fraction[]) (input.readObject());
```

`input.readObject()` returns `Fraction`, but you are trying to cast it to `Fraction[]`, which is not a compatible type.  You could read multiple `Fraction`s into an array to achieve the same result, though.  You could use an `ArrayList` to do so, like this:

```
ArrayList<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList<>();

try (
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("SerialF.dat"))
) {
    while (input.available() > 0) {
        fractions.add((Fraction) input.readObject);
        
    }
}

Fraction[] updatedFractions = fractions.toArray(new Fraction[0]);

for (Fraction fraction : updatedFractions) {
    System.out.println(fraction);
}
```